# MySql Replication Questions

Tags: mysql, replication

I am looking at switching from a standalone single MySql server to a Master->Slave Replication setup (using 2 servers). Currently there are a number of heavy write (insert/update/delete) jobs (for loading fresh data from external sources) that run for several hours each day. These jobs slow down "read" (selects) performance on corresponding tables. Hoping that the replication will help a little with this issue (among other challenges like backups).

### questions:

1) Does the slave replication "SQL Thread" lock reads when executing the relay log? Trying to gain more insight on how the SQL is actually executed (on the slave). I am hoping that the execution on the slave is more "optimized" (as opposed to the original statements executed on the master), so any potential locking is minimal. Otherwise, the same kind of "read" performance bottleneck exhibited on the master will trickle down to the slave.

2) From reading the docs, sounds like by default SBR is used (Statement based replication). Not sure if to change this to RBR (row based)? Or "mixed". Which would be recommended? I am inclined to stay with default, but really uncertain.

3) When some of the jobs complete, we currently run ANALYZE & OPTIMIZE to recover file space for corresponding tables where heavy delets/updates were performed. My understansing is that these commands will be replicated to the slave unless we run them with "NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG". Not sure how the slaves tables are impacted when doing lots of updates/deletes. Is it even necessary to replicate these commands to the slave? The main concern is that OPTIMIZE in particular locks the table, and on a live production site (and a large table), this is a very big problem.

Thanks in advance for any pointers/insight!

Answer (score 2):

From the look of it, the only benefit you will get from replicating the data is that the master will not need to process the reads, and if you have multiple slaves, the insertion on the slaves should be quicker as well, because the reads are distributed. How much depends on how many reads are being performed in any give time.

If this will speed up the insertion of the data into the master and slaves significantly then, you may end up with a win.

As far as locking goes, it doesn't propagate to the slave as far as I know (this is also stated in the faq below). I guess that you could optimise the slaves in rotation, so that only one is out of action at any given time.

Useful reading
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-faq.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaydee. I did review the faq (and many other pages) before posting. Having hard time finding specific answers though. For now, planning on single slave only. So I guess the crux of the question (#1) is if any performance improvement will be seen at all with this configuration? Specifically as it pertains to how the slave executes the writes (replicated over from the master)..

Comment: As far as OPTIMZE, it's not clear to me if it is necessary to have these replicated over to the slave (after many updates/deletes..)? Ideally/preferably, don't want to .. to avoid the slave locking up.

Comment: If you only have a single slave I can only imagine a rather modest increase in speed, coming from distributing reads between the two servers. Remember that the slave has to perform all the writes that the master has. As far as OPTIMISE goes, the documentation suggests that you don't have to replicate them at all.

Comment: I am thinking of turning off replication on the slave during the high load times on the master (batch jobs running). Then upon completion, direct slave traffic to master (from application layer) and turn replication back on the slave (so it catches up). As far as OPTIMIZE goes, where did you see that you don't have to replicate that? Can you point me to those docs? Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html "By default, OPTIMIZE TABLE statements are written to the binary log so that they will be replicated to replication slaves. Logging can be suppressed with the optional NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG keyword or its alias LOCAL. "

Comment: This just means that no explicit command/language is required for the command to be replicated across to the slave/s. My question is whether or not it is even necessary to run OPTIMIZE on slaves (implicitly as above or explicitly). I believe the probable answer is that indeed it has to be run after heavy deletes/updates (just like it is run on master). I just was not sure if there was any special magic with the replication process that allows you to skip this expensive step..Thanks

Comment: Sorry, mis-understood. With the sql statement replication, there is no special magic AFAIK. So if you want the slave tables optimised, you would have to run OPTIMISE on them. Again more slaves would give a greater increase in speed as you could optimise them in rotation taking one of line at a time.